# How does one attach an ID to an exchange appointment attendee programatically with C#?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to add attendees to an exchange Appointment, and I'm having difficulty. I need the attendees to have an ID since some of the attendees do not have unique email addresses, so I am doing he following:

```
        foreach (Student student in Students)
        {

            if (student.hasEmail)
            {
                Attendee attendee = new Attendee(student.Email);
                attendee.Id = new ItemId(student.Id);
                addRequiredAttendee(attendee);
            }
            else
            {
                String name = student.LastName + ", " + student.FirstName;
                Attendee attendee = new Attendee(name);
                attendee.Id = new ItemId(student.Id);
                addRequiredAttendee(attendee);
            }

        }
```

However, when I run:

```
appointment.Save(calendar.Id, SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```

I get an error and it doesn't send. I don't understand what the problem is. When I send without adding the ID it works fine. Has anyone experienced a problem like this? what are the specifications for setting an ID? I can't find any documentation on it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation of Attendee](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.attendee(v=exchg.80).aspx) we see that `Attendee` inherits from `EmailAddress`. An email address is required, as the appointment invitation needs to be sent somewhere. Setting an Id will not help.

Depending on your requirements you might be able to create a fake email address?

Comment: yeah idk I'm starting to think you can't even attach Ids to attendees with emailAddresses. When I run it while just attaching the ID to the known-emailAddress-attendee, I get the exception thrown :/

Comment: I don't think you can. What is the intention of wrapping a studentId in an ItemId object? The ItemId object has no knowledge of the Student class, and a studentId is of no use to EWS.

Comment: hmmm I mean I actually just wanted that so I could have an identifier for the attendees with no EmailAddresses, but If I just do the fake ones, that could do the trick to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a valid Email Address format for that to work (eg the error your getting should be indicating that) in your case you should just be able to fake the address eg

String name = student.LastName + ", " + student.FirstName;
   String Email = name + "@fakeDomain.com";

Cheers
Glen

Comment: I just gave this a try and still no luck unfortunately :(

Comment: I appreciate the fake email address idea though. I am actually just going to use that as my Id. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I've found that you cannot attach an Id to an attendee that has an emailAddress. This is what is says on the EmailAddress.Id documetation page:

> The Address property should be set to a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) when the Id property is used.

What I'm doing now is just creating a fake email for the students with no emails, and using that fake email as its identifier.